# Regex to find constant literal guard by two special characters... Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression that will match only the patterns begins with the symbol **$** followed by any character or number or special letter, further followed by named **@STRING_LITERAL@$**.

There can be any universal character present between starting $ and beginning of **@STRING_LITERAL@$**.

E.g.

1. Lorem Ipsum $@COUNTRY_NAME@$ ipsum lorem 0.
2. Lorem Ipsum $AMERICA@COUNTRY_NAME@$ ipsum lorem 1.
3. Lorem Ipsum $...@COUNTRY_NAME@$ ipsum lorem 2.
4. Lorem Ipsum $abcd@RANDOM_STRING@$ ipsum lorem 3.
5. Lorem Ipsum $Tesla@MY_CAR@$ ipsum lorem 4.

There can be many such patterns present in the para so have to explicitly target them name-wise then replace it.

RegEx is not my strength, I tried to assemble randomly the pieces together but none have worked. Below is one o the example that I tried.

```
(?<=\$)($)(.*)(\@string_literal\@$)(?=\$)
```

Comment: Should only the bold values match?

Comment: No No, All, Editing the question

Comment: Like this? `\$[^@]*@[^$]*@\$` https://regex101.com/r/N6TrYx/1

Comment: Partially, Your answer is right. But I want to match named string literal as well coz para may have many such other expressions. So I need to lookup for patterns having e.g. @COUNTRY_NAME@ in it. I will find such patterns then substitute the original value there.

Comment: You could list them using an alternation `\$[^@]*@(?:COUNTRY_NAME|RANDOM_STRING|MY_CAR)@\$` https://regex101.com/r/HYHbnn/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, you probably want to add the `$` into the negated character class to prevent matching from stray dollar signs onwards, say: `A 100$ car Lorem Ipsum $Tesla@MY_CAR@$ ipsum lorem 4.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\$[^@]*@.*?@\$
```

- `\$` Match `$~
- `[^@]*@` Match 0+ times any char except `@`, then match the `@`
- `.*?@\$` Match as least as possible chars until the first occurrence of `@$`

**Note** that if you don't want to match `$` in between, you can add it to the negated character class `[^@$]*@` as pointed out in the comments by [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WcffF3/1)

Or a more specific pattern could be listing all the alternatives

```
\$[^@]*@(?:COUNTRY_NAME|RANDOM_STRING|MY_CAR)@\$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HYHbnn/1)